# how to select from $('[name="test"]') table result in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well to make myself clear let's start with the following example:

```js
function validation(){
    $("[name='test']").focus();
      // my goal is to focus on the 'name' radio button
      //$("[name='test'] return an array with 2 items, but i don't know how to select 
      //an item, i know  that i can use id to skip the problem but this 
//won't teach me how to use jQuery
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
name: <input name="test" type="radio" /><br>
age : <input name="test" type="radio" /><br>  
  <input type="button" onclick="validation()" value = "ok" />
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fix your attribute selector by closing with a `")`

```
 $("[name='test']").focus();
```

Next, you can select specific elements with alot of different pseudo selectors like [:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), [:last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/), [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), [nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), etc...

```
$("[name='test']:first").focus();
```

```js
$("[name='test']:first").focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
name: <input name="test" type="radio" /><br>
age : <input name="test" type="radio" /><br>  
  <input type="button" onclick="validation()" value = "ok" />
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set focus use `:first` selector

```
$("[name='test']:first").focus();
```

OR, You can use [`.eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/#eq-index)

```
$("[name='test']").eq(0).focus();
```